# Background Color Settings for Newsletter Popup

Tags: magento2, css, popup

I have created some buttons in the magento2 backend :
One is for the background color of the popup, the other is for the font color of the popup.
I have tried everything but nothing is working, what can i do?

Comment: Please add more information to the question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/O8e0z08
These are the backend and the frontend pics
I dont know how to change the background and the font color of the newsletter popup with this buttons
I need to change something in the phtml file?

Comment: These functionalities are already in the extension you are using?

Comment: No.I've created them from 0.

Comment: Did you call the css for those font color and backgroud color in your module?

Comment: No...i've just created a Color.php file and i downloaded the jcolor.js file from here http://jscolor.com/

Comment: Can you post the system.xml and newsletter template file code on your question?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kj5tJCw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the color and colorsample like below:

```
$background_color_popup_style = "style=background-color:#".$block->getConfig('color');
$color_popup_style = "style=color:#".$block->getConfig('colorsample');
```

Comment: I pasted the strings but the popup is still white..

Comment: I have updated the code. # was not there. Please check and update again.

Comment: update: there is another mistake in the strings. It's getConfig, not, getCofig (anyway i'm trying right now if it works!).Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Comment: Typo mistake. It should work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: where i have to put this strings https://imgur.com/JdrXR7r
Because now the upper part of the page is green (i set it from the button )

Comment: Now its working?

Comment: still having problems..

Comment: Are you getting values?

Comment: Are you getting values from $block->getConfig('color') and $block->getConfig('colorsample')?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CY0zHxa Update:Seems like its working!I need to set the background color in the right way.
The font color is working without any problem!THANKS A LOT!!